# values in double quotes not working in export to excel

Tags: java, excel

In my export to excel functionality that is written in java the values in double quotes are getting disappeared in the excel downloaded. is there any work around for this one ?

Answer (score 1):

```
How you are trying to export the data into excel? please post?

Simple example with Apache POI-
{
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Test Export");
        Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
//cell value in double quotes  
        data.put("2", new Object[] {"1", "\"abc\""});
        data.put("3", new Object[] {"2", "\"xyz\""});
        Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
        }
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out =new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/rahul/Desktop/testExport.xls"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();     
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Actually we are using our own framework to do export to excel. we will be using just a jsp tag.

Comment: could you add some code snippet to have an idea about your export utility..check if this can help- [web page to excel](http://www.quicklyjava.com/export-web-page-to-excel/)